# STR_TO_DATE is not working for query separated by IF condition in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

Need to fetch the record from MYSQL with given from and to dates. The dates are defined as VARCHAR in the database. How to use `STR_TO_DATE(?, '%d/%m/%Y')` in laravel?

I already tried using `DB::raw("STR_TO_DATE(due_date, '%d/%m/%Y')")`

```
$from_date = "12/08/2019";
$to_date = "12/12/2020";
$from_date_raw = DB::raw("STR_TO_DATE('".$from_date."', '%d/%m/%Y')");
$to_date_raw = DB::raw("STR_TO_DATE('".$to_date."', '%d/%m/%Y')");
$due_date_raw = DB::raw("STR_TO_DATE('due_date', '%d/%m/%Y')");
$query = DB::table('due_details')->where('amount', '>', 0);
if ($from_date != null && $to_date != null) {
    $query->whereBetween($due_date_raw, [$from_date_raw, $to_date_raw]);
} else if ($from_date != null) {
    $query->where($due_date_raw, '>=', $from_date_raw);
} else if ($to_date != null) {
    $query->where($due_date_raw, '<=', $to_date_raw);
}
$data = $query->orderBy('id', 'asc')->get();
```

I expect the data between those given dates.given table('due_details') data.

It works when I run it on the command line, but not from my GUI.

Comment: This is exactly the same question as you posted earlier. Did you not make the correction I said you needed? i.e. it should be `$due_date_raw = DB::raw("STR_TO_DATE(due_date, '%d/%m/%Y')");`

Comment: I have got an answer. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @porkodim if you have an answer, please either post it as an answer to this question or delete the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

should not put quotes for column name due_date. It works fine.
DB::raw("STR_TO_DATE(due_date, '%d/%m/%Y')")